# Can tension be greater than the external forces in this case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

In this case the blocks are not moving and the forces and coefficients of friction are given. Mass of block A is 10kg and mass of B is 20kg. It asks for the tension in the string. The answer gives that the tension is 40N. But I think that $40\leq T \leq160$. The book has solved the question by taking friction on 'B' as limiting and friction on 'A' as static. But I think both the friction could be static and tension can be anything in the above range. Am I correct?

Comment: We need the masses of the two blocks

Comment: Oh I'm sorry the mass of block A is 10kg and of block B is 20kg

Comment: The computed numbers are correct; i.e. as the question is worded, you are technically correct. However, you are missing the unstated but conventional, taken-for-granted-to-not-need-mentioning assumption that the system was originally at rest and without tension, and slowly pulled into the observed scenario. Then the answer key is the only possible answer, up to vibrational uncertainties.

Comment: The tension can never exceed 120N which is the maximum of the applied forces. If block A was massless and block B weighed as much as the earth then $T=120$. If it was the other way around, then $T=100$.  Those are the limits for tension.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou if the system was originally pulled to T=160N before being lowered onto the table and then the external forces slowly reduced to those values, then it can be. The OP is technically correct. It is just that this is way too contrived to be considered a reasonable solution.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Friction may be resisting the tendency for the tension to pull the blocks together, rather than resisting the tendency for the applied force to pull the blocks apart - friction could conceivably point in either direction here. If the string is elastic, you wouldn't need to pull either block as hard as the string tension alone required, as you're being helped by friction. Unusual, but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the masses are in equilibrium, the sum of forces are zero for each of them.

Supposing the friction forces rightward in A and leftward in B, they do most of the 'job' allowing minimum tension:

For the mass A, the maximum friction force is $0,9*10*10 = 90N$. As the force leftward is $120N$, the tension must be at least $30N$ for A be in equilibrium.

For the mass B, the maximum friction force is $0,3*20*10 = 60N$. As the force rightward is $100N$,the tension must be at least $40N$ for B be in equilibrium.

So, we conclude that the tension is at least $40N$, with the friction force on mass B reaching the maximum of $60N$, and on mass A reaching $80N$, below the maximum of $90N$.

It is however also possible to suppose that the friction force is leftward on A and rightward on B. In that case, the rope does most of the 'job' requiring maximum tension:

For the mass A, the maximum friction force is $90N$. As the force leftward is $120N$, the tension must be maximum of $210N$ for A be in equilibrium.

For the mass B, the maximum friction force is $60N$. As the force rightward is $100N$,the tension must be maximum $160N$ for B be in equilibrium.

So, we conclude that the maximum tension is $160N$, with the friction force on mass B reaching the maximum of $60N$, and on mass A reaching $40N$, below the maximum of $90N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Without external forces, the highest possible tension exists when both masses are at their traction limit.

This would be

$$\begin{aligned}
  F_A & = \mu_A M_A g = 0.9 (10) 10 = 90 \;\rm N\\
  F_B & = \mu_B M_B g = 0.3 (20) 10 = 60 \;\rm N\\
\end{aligned}$$

If the friction is acting in an opposing fashion to keep the tension tight then

$$ T_{\rm max} = 90 + 60 = 150 \;\rm N$$

But now you can start adding external forces in equal and opposite fashion and it will add to the tension *and* keep the blocks from moving. Only an imbalance of external forces might cause the blocks to move.

So at the limit, to get a string tension of $T$, you need to add the following applied forces to the two block masses

$$\begin{aligned} 
 P_A &= 90 + T\\
 P_B &= 60 + T\\
\end{aligned} $$

Doing the free body diagram and balance of forces you have

$$ \begin{aligned}
  -P_A + \mu_A M_A g + T & = 0 \\
   P_B - \mu_B M_B g - T & = 0
\end{aligned} $$

which is solved by the above equations for $P_A$ and $P_B$ given that $\mu_A=0.9$, $\mu_B=0.3$, $M_A=10$, $M_B=20$ and $g=10$.

As a requirement $P_A - P_B = 30$ to keep things at the traction limit.

So as long as this is maintained $T$ can be anything.

The exact solutions to the traction limits give that friction can act in both left or right directions are:

$$\begin{aligned}
  P_A & = T \pm \mu_A M_A g & P_B & = T  \pm \mu_B M_B g \\
\end{aligned}$$

For *any* value of $T$.